# Can I plant a Nordmann Christmas Tree in my garden?

Tags: trees

I have a lovely Christmas tree that is in a pot, is it ok for these to be planted in a garden ? Not sure how I post a photo?

Comment: Hi, Y Hall and welcome to the site! Images can be added by clicking the "edit" button just below the question and then clicking the image icon that will appear above the original text.

Answer (score 2):

That rather depends on how large your garden is - in the ground, Abies nordmanniana (Nordmann fir) reaches up to 12 metres with a spread of 4-8 metres over time. Great in a large garden, not so good in a suburban small area. It also depends on where you are in the world - if its somewhere very hot and dry, it won't do too well. It prefers neutral to acid soil ph - it's not too keen on alkaline, limey soils and won't do well planted in that type of soil. Growing information here https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/53/i-Abies-nordmanniana-i/Details

Comment: Whilst I tend to dislike the mentality that only small trees are suitable for small gardens, as it is a conifer pruning and underplanting opportunities will be limited so, yes, really for larger gardens.